# Como puedo cambiar el tamaño de la fuente en un drawString

Tags: java, string, fuentes

Estoy tratando de que en la pantalla se muestre la fuente en un tamaño mas grande, una posible solucion que encontre fue esta:

```
  public void mostrarLetras(Graphics g){        
    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    //(String, tipo de fuente, tamaño)
    Font fuente = new Font("LETRAS = " + getValorCambiante(), Font.BOLD, 36);
    g.drawString((AttributedCharacterIterator) fuente, 15, 520);
}
```

cabe aclarar dos cosas, la primera es que al ejecutar la aplicación obtengo el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Y segunda cosa para aclarar es que estoy haciendo todo esto en un canvas, es por eso el motivo de usar el metodo Graphics.

De antemano gracias.

Comment: Proba eliminar el casteo en esa linea **g.drawString((AttributedCharacterIterator) fuente, 15, 520);**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero es que debes redefinir el método `paintComponent()` o `paint()` esto depende de como estas implementando tu código, algo no menor. Entonces un ejemplo que seria mas o menos así:

```
public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
  g.setColor( Color.BLUE );
  g.setFont( new Font( "Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 46 ) );
  g.drawString( "Hola Mundo Java!", 10, 100 );
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Bonus Tip:**

Si posiblemente ves la fuente como algo de baja calidad, sin suavizado en los pixeles, la API `Graphics2D` nos ayuda en esto, solo hay que usar un método que nos proporciona, `setRenderingHint()`

```
public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
  Graphics2D G2D = (Graphics2D) g;
  G2D.setColor( Color.BLUE );
  G2D.setFont( new Font( "Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 46 ) );
  G2D.setRenderingHint( RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_LCD_HRGB );
  G2D.drawString( "Hola Mundo Java!", 10, 100 );
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]